# how to link website to a facebook group, tweeter, youtube?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml-1.0-strict

I want to link the website to facebook group, tweeter, youtube, VK. So that when I click on the social media button on the website, I will follow them.

Comment: You need their API. Google it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like for facebook you need like button.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Twitter follow button.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button

Youtube subscribe button.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

Vk like button.

https://vk.com/dev/Like

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways

- With an `<a>` tag
- With `<form>`

---

**Anchor tag** (`<a>`)

.html file

```
<a href="http://facebook.com" class="button">Facebook</a>
```

.css file

```
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

If you use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) then do the following:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com" class="btn btn-default">Facebook</a>
```

---

**Forms** (`<form>`)

.html file

```
<form action="http://facebook.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Facebook" />
</form>
```

*Or* (with JavaScript)

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://facebook.com';" value="Facebook" />
```